# Как переписать этот кусок кода на Python

Tags: javascript, python

Есть обычный вложенный цикл на JavaScript:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - k + 1; i++) {
    let summa = 0 
    for (let j = i; j < i + k; j++) {
      summa += numbers[j]
    }
```

Как его переписать на Python?

Comment: А в чем возникли сложности?

Comment: @insolor во втором цикле. Я понимаю, что в первом обычный `for i in range(0, len(numbers) - k + 1)`, но во втором что-то не получается. Может, просто туплю

Comment: Во втором обычный `range(i, i + k)`

Comment: @insolor благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне внутренний цикл вообще не нужен, можно использовать встроенную функцию `sum` и срезы:

```py
for i in range(len(numbers) - k):
    summa = sum(numbers[i:i+k])
```